# Does Chrome use XPath 2.0?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I was under impression that all latest browsers are with XPath 2 now. When I use `lower-case()` and `uppser-case()` (functions introduced in version 2)  Chrome throws a syntax error. However, their older alternative `translate()` works fine.

Is this a bug or does the latest Chrome actually use XPath 1? Is there a command / way to find out the XPath version?

```
// Finds the element as expected.
$x('//h2/text()[. = "Delete"]') 

// Doesn't find the element (also expected).
$x('//h2/text()[. = "delete"]') 

// SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//h2/text()[lower-case(.) = "delete"]' is not a valid XPath expression.
$x('//h2/text()[lower-case(.) = "delete"]')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What browsers support Xpath 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658799/what-browsers-support-xpath-2-0)

Comment: I saw 16658799. Did you read the answer carefully? Do it first then. And then read mine again…

Comment: None of the "big" browsers use XPath 2. There's your answer. Simple.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**No, Chrome uses XPath 1.0.**

You can simplify your XPath expression to just a v2.0 function to see this:

```
$x("lower-case('ABC')")
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'lower-case('ABC')' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Trying any other XPath 2.0 function such as `current-date()` will yield a similar error.

**There is no built-in way of definitively determining the version of an XPath implementation other than by such probes.**

XSLT, on the other hand, has `system-property('xsl:version')` for determining version 1.0 versus 2.0.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: The answer shows you how you can check, but, yes, it's still the case in 2017 with Chrome v55: Only XPath 1.0 is supported, not XPath 2.0.

Comment: Still the case in Nov 2018

Comment: Still the case in Aug 2019 with Chrome 76

Comment: Hello from May 2020, Covid-19 lockdown! Still no support in Chrome 81.

Comment: This sucks. Why is this still not supported? I'll have to write ugly xpath code just to do simple case sensitive searches.

Edit:
Apparently, this is never going to be supported https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/903#issuecomment-707748069

Comment: Greetings from October, 2021: Still no support in Chrome 94.

Comment: its dec 2022. still no support in chrome Version 108

Answer (score 12):

Google Chrome (or Chromium) still uses [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) thus is limited to XPath 1.0. Cf. [this Readme from the source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/libxml/README.chromium).

Comment: Here's a still-live link from StackOverflow about [libxml2 not implementing XPath 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164535/290085).