# How to include a line break in an XPath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

Is there a way to add a line break to an XPath expression?

Here is my current expression which isn't working

```
{concat(@Parameter1, $NullObj, @Parameter2)}
```

Where the variable `$NullObj` is equal to `&#xa;` the hex value of the LINEFEED character.

This outputs as "Parameter1 Parameter2."

EDIT: Unfortunately, I'm using Xpath / Xsl 1.0.

EDIT: Sample code below. XML:

```
<Post>
  <Title>Title Text</Title>
  <Body>Body Text </Body>
  <Author>Author Name</Author>
</Post>
```

Sample XSL

```
<xsl:Variable name="NullObj">
<xsl:value-of select="'&#xa;'" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Edit2: Full Xpath context, as requested:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat("The title is", @Title, $NullObj, "The Body reads:", @Body, $NullObj, "The Author is", @Author)" />
```

The resulting output does not include line breaks. Am I missing something fundamental? 
I've also tried replacing `&#xa;` with `&#10;`, but no luck. 
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line breaks (\n) via concat() in XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312794/line-breaks-n-via-concat-in-xpath)

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example.

Comment: thanks @kjhughes. I tried using this solution and it didn't work. It might be because the verion of XPath + XSL I'm using are not 2.0. I should have clarified that in my original post.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, added. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: That's still not reproducible. Please show the XPath expression in its full XSLT context. See: [mcve]

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry about that. I've added the full tag.

Comment: I don't think you understand what "complete" means. It means I should be able to copy/paste your code and run it *as is* without having to add anything. -- Also, the code makes no sense: `Title`, `Body` and `Author` are not attributes. -- Note also that XML is case-sensitive: `<xsl:Variable name="NullObj">` would produce an error. -- And your expression is invalid on account of nested quotes.

Comment: May be you are using a MAC? Than the new line is a `&#xd;`

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate what is meant by [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="NullObj">
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xa;'" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/Post">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('The title is: ', Title, $NullObj, 'The Body reads:', Body, $NullObj, 'The Author is: ', Author)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your example input, returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Post>The title is: Title Text
The Body reads:Body Text 
The Author is: Author Name</Post>
```

As you can see, the line breaks are where you expect them to be.

---

### Edit:

Apparently, you are trying to produce **HTML output** - so the correct answer would be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('The title is: ', Title)" />
<br/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('The Body reads:', Body)" />
<br/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('The Author is: ', Author)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The problem turned out to be a white-space issue. Apparently setting it to anything other than "pre" would ignore the Xpath line breaks in IE.

Comment: Well, if you are producing HTML to be viewed in a web browser - **and how are we supposed to know that from the snippets you have posted?!!** - then you really should be producing **HTML line breaks** i.e. `<br>`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br Then you won't need to resort to  using the `<pre>` tag which causes a number of other effects you probably don't want (such as monospaced font).