# xpath - how to get text from node in Quora?

Tags: xpath

I have copied the xpath Chrome returns for a certain node

//*[@id="__w2_cEfEsuQ_list_item"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]

Executing this in the console of Chrome returns

```
[a]
    0: a
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

0 can be expanded and contains a lot of subnodes (I removed most of them because SO complained about too much code in my question), like this:

```
accessKey: ""
tagName: "A"
target: ""
text: "38 Answers"
textContent: "38 Answers"
title: ""
translate: true
type: ""
username: ""
```

I want an xpath that returns the `textContent` and `text` nodes. I have tried different variations on `//*[@id="__w2_cEfEsuQ_list_item"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/text()` but none has worked. How do I do?

Comment: IIRC this is only possible using XPath-2.0. If you're stuck with XPath-1.0, you're out of luck this way.

Comment: What version of Xpath is supported by the console in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome console features indeed [only XPath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455351/does-chrome-use-xpath-2-0).
Nonetheless, getting the `text()` should work as expected.

To Run XPath queries on the current page directly from Chrome's console,

- Open the console (`F12`, `cmd-opt-J` on a Mac), then
- placing your query inside [`$x("")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22573161/8291949) and run it.

If you want to print all text elements found by the locator in the console (or do other stuff) just call `.forEach`

```
$x('//*[@id="__w2_cEfEsuQ_list_item"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/text()').forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item);});
```

or access the elements of the result array directly using the index `$x("//p/text()")[0]`