# How to select all text via XPath in Chrome console

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome, xpath

In Chrome's Debugger's Console window, I'd like to convert (sort of flatten) an array to string, like this:

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">a</div>
  <div class="bar">b</div>
</div>
```

and get this result:
`a b`

This works but seems like a hack:

```xml
var arr = $x('//*[@class="foo"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()')
for (i in arr) { console.log(arr[i].data); };
```

But `text()`, of course, returns an array, whereas I just want the text.

Comment: Note that there is no element with `@id="foo"`. Did you mean `@class="foo"`?

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

To get all of the text of an XML document in XPath 1.0, use `string()`:

```
> $x("string(/)")
< '\n  a\n  b\n'
```

To normalize whitespace (again, XPath 1.0), use `normalize-space()`:

```
> $x("normalize-space(/)")
< 'a b'
```

Substitute any element-selecting XPath (such as `//*[@class="foo"]`) for `/` to limit the text to descendants of (the first of, in XPath 1.0) the selected elements.

Note that `string-join()` requires [XPath 2.0, which is not supported in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25455351/290085).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to get single string that *consists of both child text values joined with space char*

```
string-join(//div[@class="bar"], " ")
```

or

```
string(//div[@class="foo"])
```

to get *string representation of parent node*

Comment: In the Chrome (103.0.5060.114) debugger console, I get an error no matter what arguments I send to string-join, for example: `string-join("hi")
VM9617:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: string is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: As kjhughes mentioned in his answer,`string-join()` is an XPath 2.0 function and therefore not available in the Browser's XPath 1.0 implementation.