# XPath 3 in browser

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xpath, browser

When we see conformance chart, such as https://caniuse.com/#search=xpath and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/domlevel3xpath/?q=xpath, it's usually about [DOM Level 3 XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-XPath-20040226/) that focuses on accessing DOM object using XPath **1.0**, but not necessarily XPath 3.0 or higher.

Question 1 - Is there any explicit version requirement for browsers by W3C etc. to support newer versions of XPath?

This XPath 1.0 feature works:

```
document.evaluate(
  'normalize-space(" X  ")',
  document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null ).stringValue

// => "X"
```

But this XPath 3.0 inline-function feature ([ref](https://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol10/html/Novatchev01/BalisageVol10-Novatchev01.html)) throws:

```
document.evaluate(
  'let $incr := function($n as xs:integer) as xs:integer { $n +1 } return $incr(2)',
  document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null ).stringValue
```

Edge:

> XPATH15001: XPath query "let $incr := function($n as xs:integer) as xs:integer { $n +1 } return $incr(2)" not supported

Firefox:

> SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Question 2 - If XPath 3.0 is allowed in browser, assuming bug in my code; then how about v3.1 features (such as [arrow-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath_3#New_features_in_XPath_3.1)), are those also allowed?

Answer (score 5):

**[No browsers support XPath 2.0 natively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16658799/290085), let alone XPath 3.0.**

Note also that [XPath, unlike XSLT, doesn't have an intrinsic way of determining the version of an XPath implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25455588/290085) other than trying a function supported by a given version and observing whether an error occurs, as you've done.

Comment: Since the standard is not requiring newer XPath support, no effort is being made.

Comment: XPath2.0 was superseded by XPath3.0 in 2014.

Comment: A standard can dictate terms of compliance but cannot compel adoption.

Answer (score 3):

Saxon-JS provides an implementation of XPath 3.1 that runs in any browser (it's written in Javascript).

However, it doesn't (yet) support higher-order functions, so the example using an inline function won't work.

**July 2020 Update**

Saxon-JS 2.0 supports the whole of XPath 3.1 including higher order functions.